Is there any client-side storage that is safe from browser extensions?
LocalStorage, SessionStorage and IndexedDB can all be easily accessed by browser extensions through content scripts. Yes, the extensions need user permission, but users are dumb enough to give extensions access to all websites.
So is there any client-side storage that is actually secure and can be accessed by your JavaScript, e.g. one where you can safely store the user's private key for an end-to-end encrypted web app?
(I know HttpOnly cookies can't be accessed by extensions, but my JavaScript can't access them either.)

I would suspect that anything which can be accessed by JavaScript in the browser can also be accessed by extensions in the browser.

AFAIK, browser extensions can also read and modify httpOnly cookies.

If your code is executing in a "compromised" environment, there's basically nothing your code can do to protect itself. It's up to the user to keep their environment safe.
